# Cannot figure out why it throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, loops, exception, concurrentmodification

I've got the ConcurrentModificationException and do not know why. I know that trying to iterate through a list using for loops and deleting elements inside the loop block is bad idea and can throw such exception, but I have no idea how to fix it in my case.

```
 private static final List<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            originalList.add(i);
        }


        final int MAX_GROUP_SIZE = 5;
        int partitionSize = 4;

        List<List<Integer>> partitions = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < originalList.size(); i += partitionSize) {
            partitions.add(originalList.subList(i,
                    Math.min(i + partitionSize, originalList.size())));
        }

        int lastGroupSize = partitions.get(partitions.size() - 1).size();

        if (lastGroupSize < partitionSize && partitions.size() > lastGroupSize){
            List<Integer> lastGroup = partitions.remove(partitions.size() - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < lastGroupSize; i++) {
                partitions.get(i).add(lastGroup.get(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("GROUPS: " + partitions.size());
        printGroups(new LinkedList<>(partitions));
    }
```

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: @marstran in `partitions.get(i).add(lastGroup.get(i));`

Comment: In this case, at the second iteration it throws this exception while getting an element from "partitions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your calls to [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) don't create new lists. As the javadoc says it:

> Returns a **view** of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

The javadoc also says:

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is *structurally modified* in any way other than via the returned list.

When you call `partitions.get(i).add(...)`, you're *structurally modifying* `originalList`, causing the error.

I don't believe you intended that, so to fix the problem, you just need to make sure your sub-lists are independent of the original list, i.e. copies, which is easy to do:

```
new ArrayList<>(originalList.subList(...))
```

Using the [`ArrayList(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) constructor will create a copy of the sub-list.

So, change this statement:

```
partitions.add(originalList.subList(i,
        Math.min(i + partitionSize, originalList.size())));
```

to this:

```
partitions.add(new ArrayList<>(originalList.subList(i,
        Math.min(i + partitionSize, originalList.size()))));
```

Answer (score -2):

You should never iterate the list and perform updating actions while doing so (where updating means adding or removing elements). This is a recipe for disaster.

In order to resolve this there are three possible scenarios to follow:

1) Copy the list, iterate over the copy and remove from the original one.

```
for (var number : new ArrayList<>(original)) {
    if (element > 10) {
        original.remove(element);
    }
}
```

2) Use Streams

```
List<Integer> filtered = original.stream()
                                 .filter(i -> i > 10)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

3) Use an iterator to loop over the list

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = original.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNex()) {
    Integer number = iterator.next();
    if (number > 10) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer streams.